# HTML to printable format

Tags: php, html, printing

Currently using a HTML to PDF converter written in PHP to attach a printable readonly page to an email.

This can be a little temperamental at the best of times, producing strange results.  I was wondering if there was perhaps a better option to achieve this end result?

(Granted the end PDF is not entirely "un-editable", but it does the job for my purposes atm)

I have been thinking perhaps: 
- HTML > image
- Attach HTML and advise the mail client to open the file in a application

Can anyone offer any advice?
Thanks

Comment: It's going to be very difficult to offer advice here, as you're not giving any info about what your current solution (which one?) doesn't do sufficiently. Can you show some screen shots?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why can't you just attach an HTML page with content-type attachment? That way it will be readonly, would look like an attachment, and you will be able to print it.

Comment: The current solution is using html2pdf which falls over on things such as nested tables and colspans.

I am working to a set of arbitrary requirements, that don't make an awful lot of technical sense, ie "html can be edited pdf cannot" - this is a false statement, i know.  But i am feeling-around for an alternative solution which _might_ be easier than correcting an awful lot of people's stubborn perceptions.

Comment: I _did_ imply attaching the html as an attachment using the content-type to "advise" the mail client... as something I have already considered, more alternatives/elaboration on such an approach or other approaches and their pros and cons is what I am after.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to your current solution. You could always write a stylesheet for print.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />`

And then email this page to your clients? Or simply attach this page itself.